# Xamarin ToolbarItem Icon color on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, icons, toolbaritems

I have a `TabbedPage` with a `ToolbarItems` with Item that have an Icon.

On iOS the icon's color is like a text (defined by iOS theme), but in Android the color of the icon is the color that tha physically image have.

iOS:
[image: iOS]

Android:
[image: Android]

How can I set the color of the icon like the color of the text?